# Short proof that $\rho^\prime(x,y) = \min\{1,\rho(x,y)\}$ is a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space. Define $\rho^\prime: X \times X \to \mathbf{R}$ by $\rho^\prime (x,y) = \min\{1,\rho(x,y)\}$ for all $x, y \in X$. Does anyone know of a short proof that $\rho^\prime$ satisfies the triangle inequality? It is easy (but tedious) to verify by checking cases.

Comment: Hint: The only relevant features are that $\rho'=h\circ\rho$ where the function $h$ is nondecreasing, concave, and such that $h(0)=0$.

Comment: It doesn't seem that tedious to check it at all...

Comment: (The nature of original metric makes no difference, and the proof there covers the general case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x,y,z \in X$, we have
$$
\rho'(x,z) = \\
\min\{1,\rho(x,z)\} \leq\\
\min\{1,\rho(x,y) + \rho(y,z)\} \leq\\
\min\{1,\rho(x,y)\} + \min\{1,\rho(y,z)\} =\\
\rho'(x,y) + \rho'(y,z)
$$
In order to make this proof work, it suffices to show that the two inequalities used actually hold.  In particular, we need to show (or perhaps simply state) the following:

- For the first: if $a \leq b$, then $\min\{1,a\} \leq \min\{1,b\}$
- For the second: for any non-negative real $a,b$, $\min\{1,a+b\} \leq \min\{1,a\} + \min\{1,b\}$

The first statement can be checked in two cases.  The second might require $3$.

I think you'll find it easier to prove these statements separately than to separate the whole proof into cases.

Comment: If we put any bounded number $c$ instead of 1 in the first statement, then the inequality holds? I mean $\min \{c,a\} \leq \min \{c,b\}$.

Comment: @Saeed yes, the inequality holds for any $c$.

Comment: Also, for the second one?

Comment: @Saeed it certainly holds if $c \geq 0$, but I'm not sure about the general case off the top of my head

Comment: I meant $c \leq 0$.

Comment: @Saeed no idea. Feel free to post a question about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to check different cases, keep in mind that
$\min(a,b) = \frac{a+b-|a-b|}{2}$, it might help direct calculations.

By the way, even if it is not relevant here, the same trick exists for $\max(a,b) = \frac{|a-b|+a+b}{2}$.