# Brute force way to show that $\rho(x,y) = \min\{1, d(x,y)\}$ is a metric

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Following a hint in [Short proof that $\rho^\prime(x,y) = \min\{1,\rho(x,y)\}$ is a metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307699/short-proof-that-rho-primex-y-min-1-rhox-y-is-a-metric)

I would like to use the brute force method to show that the standard bounded metric is a metric

$$\rho(x,y) = \min\{1, d(x,y)\}$$

By brute force I mean to substitute the definition of $\min$ operator which is:

$$\min(a,b) = \dfrac{a+b - |a-b|}{2}$$

So let $x,y,z \in (X, \rho)$
\begin{align}
\rho(x,z) &= \min\{1, d(x,z)\}\\
          &= \dfrac{1+d(x,z) - |1-d(x,z)|}{2}\\
          & = \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{d(x,z)}{2} - \dfrac{|1-d(x,z)|}{2}\\
          & \leq \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{d(x,y)}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{d(y,z)}{2}  - \dfrac{|1-d(x,z)|}{2} \tag{obvious}
\end{align}

If I can show that

> $$- \dfrac{|1-d(x,z)|}{2} \leq - \dfrac{|1-d(x,y)|}{2} + -
>  \dfrac{|1-d(y,z)|}{2}$$

Then I am done.

However, this seems to be really messy and difficult to show. How can I show that the above inequality holds?

Comment: Since you're already in the brute force mood, you could split the absolute values into cases.

Comment: Your inequality doesn't generally hold. Consider $x=z$ but $d(x,y)=d(y,z)>2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check three things.

We have $\rho(x,y)=\rho(y,x)$ trivially (since $\delta(x,y)=\delta(y,x)$)

We also have $\rho(x.y)=\min(1,\delta(x,y))=0\iff\delta(x,y)=0\iff x=y$

The only tricky part is the triangle inequality.

We have to show $\rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z)\leq \rho(x,z)$.

if $\rho(x,y)\neq \delta(y,z)$ or $\rho(y,z)\neq \delta(y,z)$ we have $\rho(x,y)+\rho(x,z)\geq 1 \geq \rho(x,z)$ Otherwise:

$\rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z)=\delta(x,y)+\delta(y,z)\geq\delta(x,z)\geq\min(1,\delta(x,z))=\rho(x,z)$

Answer (score 1):

In this case worth to calculate step by step. We have eight (8) possibilites.

Look: we want to show that $\rho^\prime(x,z) \leq \rho^\prime(x,y) + \rho^\prime(y,z)$, ok?!

This is that $\min\{1, d(x,z)\} \leq \min\{1, d(x,y)\} + \min\{1, d(y,z)\}$.

- Notice that, if $\rho^\prime(x,z)=d(x,z)=\min\{1, d(x,z)\}$ **(this hypothesis say that $d(x,z)\leq 1$ it is very important for you understand the solution following)** than we have four (4) possibilites:

  1. $d(x,z) \leq 1+ 1$;
  2. $d(x,z) \leq 1+ d(y,z);$
  3. $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) +1;$
  4. $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z);$ (it's true by hypothesis that $d$ is a metric)
- Now, if $\rho^\prime(x,z)=1=\min\{1, d(x,z)\}$ we have:

  1. $1 \leq 1+ 1;$
  2. $1 \leq d(x,y) + 1;$
  3. $1 \leq 1+ d(y,z);$
  4. $1 \leq d(x,y)+ d(y,z);$ this is true by hipothesis $\rho^\prime(x,z)=1\leq d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z);$

However, by 1-8 we proof triangle inequality.