# Show that $d_1=\min(d(x,y),2)$ is a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Show that $d_1=\min(d(x,y),2)$ is a metric space if it is given that $d(x,y)$ is a metric space.

I am stuck at the triangle inequality part, to show that

$d_1(x,z)\leqslant d_1(x,y)+d_1(y,z)$ i.e to show that:

$$\min(d(x,z),2)\leqslant\min(d(y,z),2)+\min(d(x,y),2)$$

It is not a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860747/brute-force-way-to-show-that-rhox-y-min-1-dx-y-is-a-metric) "brute force" question, maybe it is a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307699/short-proof-that-rho-primex-y-min-1-rhox-y-is-a-metric), can someone please post another answers before you are colsing as duplicate, I promise to vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using that $d$ satisfies the triangle inequality
$$\min(d(x,z),2)\leqslant\min(d(y,z)+d(x,y),2)\leq \min(d(y,z),2)+\min(d(x,y),2),$$
where the second step is a property of $\min$, and uses the fact that distances are positive.

Comment: no one knows that property of min by heart.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling I am not saying that it is immediate to see or that one should know it by heart (neither did I), but that it can be easily proved by an elementary case division. Maybe I should have pointed it out in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Do it in cases.

Consider $x,y,z$.

If either $d(x,y) \ge 2$ or $d(y,z) \ge 2$ then $\min(d(x,y),2) + \min(d(y,z),2) \ge 2 \ge \min (d(x,z),2)$.

If however $d(x,y) < 2; d(y,z) <2$ then $\min(d(x,y),2) + \min(d(y,z),2) = d(x,y) + d(y,z) \ge d(x,z) \ge \min(d(x,y2),2)$.

And that's it.